# Sobolev space on manifolds and charts

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, sobolev-spaces

Let $(M,g)$ be an orientable Riemannian manifold $U \subset M$ with chart

$$ \varphi: U \rightarrow  V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$$

I wonder if one can say that

(1) "If $u \in H^k(U)$ then $v:=(u \circ \varphi^{-1}) \in H^k(V)$ and vice versa."

Here, by $H^k$ I denote the $2,k$ Sobolev space.

I tried calculating this when $k=1$:

$$\Vert u \Vert^2_{H^1} = \int\limits_U \vert u \vert^2 + \int\limits_U g^{ij} \partial_i u \partial_j u $$

and

$$ \Vert v \Vert^2_{H^1}=\int\limits_V \vert u \vert^2 + \int\limits_V  (\partial_i u )^2 $$

As far as I see, (1) should hold, if $g$ is bounded. Is that correct?

Comment: How do you know that $g^{ij}$ is bounded in your chart?

Comment: If you fix an atlas of coordinate charts, this works. If you have a smooth Riemannian metric, you can just define the Sobolev norm to be $$\|u\|_{H^k}^2 = \sum_{j=0}^{k} \int_M |\nabla^ju|^2\,dV_g$$

Comment: @Kajelad I meant that if we assume that $g$ is bounded

Comment: @User1 What does mean it mean to say that $g$ is bounded? There are no norms available except those induced by $g$ itself.

Comment: I though about $\sup\limits_{M} g_{ij}$

Comment: @User1 What does that mean? The components $g_{ij}$ aren't defined without first choosing a coordinate chart, and even then they won't be defined on all of $M$.

Comment: I am also not quite sure what this means, but in "Wave maps in general relativity" it says "Suppose $g$ is smooth with uniformly bounded 
derivatives of arbitrary order."

Answer (score 2):

From the point of view of a pedantic mathematician, the answer to your question is no. From the point of view of a physicist interested in *Wave maps in general relativity* however, you can certainly make use of the intuition that a positive answer would provide, and this intuition will be sufficient 'for all practical purposes' and not too misleading.

There are a lot of technical issues about Sobolev spaces on manifolds, even on charts. In order to keep the discussion simple, let me assume that $U$ has smooth boundary (depending on whom you ask to, this might already be part of the definition of chart on a smooth manifold). By this I mean that there exists an atlas of $M$ which, when restricted to $\partial U$, turns $\partial U$ into a smooth manifold.

What the OP probably has in mind is that $U$ is a *bounded* chart (it is not part of the standard definition of chart that the domain of the chart be a bounded set). If so, then the metric $g$ is bounded (by compactness of $\overline U$ and since $g$ extends continuously beyond $U$). Clearly the same holds for all the derivatives of $g$. This means that for every multi-index $\alpha$ there exists a constant $C_{|\alpha|}>0$ so that
$$\sup_{x\in U} \|D^\alpha g(x)\| \leq C_{|\alpha|}$$
where the norm denotes the standard norm in a suitable (depending on $\alpha$) space of tensors (equivalent to the standard norm on some Euclidean space), and $|\alpha|$ is the length of the multi-index $\alpha$. In the case $\alpha=0$ we let $D^\alpha\equiv \mathbb 1$, and the norm is simply any norm on the space of $n\times n$ matrices (all of these norms are equivalent).
Incidentally (to clarify the comments to the OP), the metric $g$ is (globally) *bounded on $M$* if the constants $C_{|\alpha|}$ can be chosen independently of the chart(s) $U$.
In this case – and only in this case –, the intuition behind (1) in the OP is correct, as discussed in some detail [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2843993/why-do-i-need-partitions-of-unity-to-define-sobolev-norms-on-compact-manifolds?rq=1).

It is instructive to see what goes wrong if $U$ is not a bounded chart. The first problem is that now $U$ can be the whole of $M$. E.g., $\mathbb R^n$ (with any metric $g$) admits a unique chart.
In the rest of the discussion we can therefore assume that $U=M$, since this does not in fact make things more complicated than they already are for unbounded $U$.
This is a problem because now the very definition of Sobolev space is in question, and there are (at least) three main competing ones:

1. closure of smooth compactly supported functions $\mathring H^k:= \overline{\{\mathcal C^\infty_c(M)\}}^{\|\cdot\|_{H^k}}$;
2. closure of smooth (possibly unbounded) functions sufficiently integrable and with sufficiently integrable derivatives $H^k := \overline{\{f\in \mathcal C^\infty(M): \|f\|_{H^k}<\infty\}}^{\|\cdot\|_{H^k}}$
3. distributions the derivatives of which are identifiable with $ L^2$-functions $W^k:= \{ f \text{ distribution on } M : D^\alpha f \in L^2, |\alpha|\leq k\}$
4. Bessel potential spaces

The $H^k$-norm is defined as in the OP.

> **Fact: these spaces do not coincide!**

Without going into the details here, counterexamples can be found in [A] (below). This suggests that, in defining Sobolev spaces on manifolds, one should take a global perspective rather than a local one. Indeed, the previous fact has dire consequences:

> **Fact:** most of the standard results on Sobolev spaces (e.g. Sobolev/Rellich–Kondrashov embedding, etc.) do not hold in this generality, and they actually might fail **very badly**, e.g. at all integrability scales $p$ (here $p=2$), and at every order $k$.

This can happen **even on $3$-dimensional manifolds with Ricci curvature bounded below by 0**.

A solution to these problems is to assume

> **Definition (*bounded geometry*)** $(M,g)$ has *bounded geometry* if (a) $(M,g)$ has injectivity radius bounded away from $0$ (i.e. $\mathrm{inj}_g M>0$) and (b) $g$ (and all its derivatives) are globally bounded.

In this case, the above definitions of Sobolev spaces coincide. Note that (a) is necessary to have well-behaved Sobolev spaces. Indeed (a) and (b) rule out two undesirable behaviours at infinity. (a) tells that the manifold cannot accumulate too much topology at infinity *at small scales*, while (b) tells that the manifold cannot explode (metrically), i.e. that it is uniformly controlled *at large scales*.
Both of these assumptions are important, and (b) is not sufficient to rule out strange phenomena in full generality.

[A] E. Hebey, *Sobolev Spaces on Riemannian Manifolds*, 1996