# Is the definition of the Sobolev space H^1(M) on a compact manifold that simple?

Tags: sobolev-spaces, compact-manifolds

In https://hebey.u-cergy.fr/NotesSharpSP.pdf right at the beginning Hebey says

> Given $(M,g)$ a smooth compact $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifold, one
>   easily defines the Sobolev spaces $H^p_k(M)$, following what is done in
>   the more traditionnal Euclidean context. For instance, when $k = 1$, and
>   $p = 2$, one may define the Sobolev space $H^1_2(M)$ as follows: for $u \in C^{\infty}(M)$, we let
>   $$\Vert u \Vert^2_{H^1_2(M)}=\Vert u \Vert^2_2+\Vert \nabla u \Vert_2^2$$ where $\Vert \cdot \Vert_p$ is the $L^p$-norm with respect to the Riemannian measure $dv(g)$. We then define $H^1_2(M)$ as the completion of
>   $C^{\infty}(M)$ with respect to $\Vert \cdot \Vert_{H^1_2(M)}$ .

How does he define it so "easily" while I see other sources where they use things such as partition of the unity to define Sobolev spaces on manifolds etc? Also, what might go wrong if we don't require $M$ to be compact?

Comment: For example here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/611961/why-is-partition-of-unity-required-in-definition-of-sobolev-space-on-manfolds

Answer (score 1):

In order to make this definition workable, one has to show the elements in your Sobolev space (which a priori are equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences of functions) can be identified with their limit in $L^p$. This corresponds to proving if a sequence $\{u_i\} \subset C^\infty(M)$ is Cauchy with respect to the norm $\lVert \cdot \rVert_{H_k^p}$ and converges to $0$ in $L^p$, then it converges to $0$ in $\lVert \cdot \rVert_{H_k^p}$. This is treated just after Definition 2.1 in ["Sobolev Spaces on Manifolds" by Hebey and Robert](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/264910370_Sobolev_spaces_on_manifolds). This where one needs to deal with the functions locally.